# using boost mpl lambda with variadic template class

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, variadic, boost-mpl

I am having a hard time understanding why the following simple program won't compile. I have a variadic template class (`my_type` below) which I want to use to transform an mpl vector. The following snippet leads to a compilation error "/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/apply_wrap.hpp:38:19: 'apply' following the 'template' keyword does not refer to a template".

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>

template <class... T>
struct my_type{};

using namespace boost::mpl;

using test_type = vector<int, double>;

// expected result is vector< my_type<int>, my_type<double> >
using result_type = transform< test_type, my_type<_> >::type; 

int main() {

}
```

Making `my_type` take a single template parameter works fine, but I would like to understand why the variadic version does not work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument expected by transform is a unary operation which you are not passing.

In your case, `my_type` is not a `metafunction` that mpl expects since it is making use of a variadic parameter list.

A `metafunction` in the simplest case exposes a `type` typedef or a `ststic bool` `value`. For eg:

```
template <typename T>
struct add_pointer {
    using type = T*;
};
```

Note how `add_pointer` converts the provided template parameter. This is an example of `unary` operation since it takes only one template parameter `T`.

In your example `my_type` is purely a type and cannot be used as a metafunction or operation as it does not satisfy the criteria of the `metafunction` as required by the `transform` metafunction which is have a `type` field to indicate the transformed type.

In some cases, a simple temmplate type is converted into a `metafunction` as explained in the `Detailed Reasoning` section below.

Doc reference : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/mpl/doc/ref/Reference/transform.html

Code:

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>

#include <type_traits>
#include <typeindex>
#include <iostream>

template <class... T>
struct my_type{};

using namespace boost::mpl;

using test_type = vector<int, double>;

template <typename T>
struct add_my_type {
    using type = my_type<T>;
};

using result_type = typename transform< test_type, add_my_type<_1> >::type; 

int main() {
    static_assert (equal<result_type, vector< my_type<int>, my_type<double> >>::value, "Nope!!");

    std::cout << typeid(result_type).name() << std::endl; 
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd6f6d0d6b711124)

**Detailed Reason**

The reason explained above is pretty brief in should be enough to answer the question. But lets dig into the details as much as I can.

DISCLAIMER: I am no expert in boost::mpl.

As per the comment below by the OP, the original code works if we change `my_type` to:

```
template <class T>
struct my_type{};
```

But that doesn't go well with what I mentioned previously i.e `operation` needs a `type` identifier. So, lets see, what mpl is doing under the hood:

`struct transform` somewhat looks like:

```
template<  
  typename Seq1 = mpl::na
, typename Seq2OrOperation = mpl::na      
, typename OperationOrInserter = mpl::na          
, typename Inserter = mpl::na             
>
struct transform {
  boost::mpl::eval_if<
        boost::mpl::or_<
            boost::mpl::is_na<OperationOrInserter>, 
            boost::mpl::is_lambda_expression<my_type<mpl_::arg<1> > >,
            boost::mpl::not_<boost::mpl::is_sequence<my_type<mpl_::arg<1> > > >,
            mpl_::bool_<false>, 
            mpl_::bool_<false> 
        >,
        boost::mpl::transform1<
            boost::mpl::vector<int, double>, 
            my_type<mpl_::arg<1>>, 
            mpl_::na
        >, 
        boost::mpl::transform2<boost::mpl::vector<int, double>,
            my_type<mpl_::arg<1> >, 
            mpl_::na, mpl_::na> 
        >

};
```

The important part to look here is the `is_lambda_expression` metafunction which basically checks if your `Operation` meets the requirement of a `metafunction`.

After applying some heavy macro and template machinery and specializations, the above check synthesises below struct:

```
template<
      typename IsLE, typename Tag
    , template< typename P1 > class F
    , typename L1
    >
struct le_result1
{
    typedef F<
          typename L1::type
        > result_;

    typedef result_ type;
};
```

Here, `F` is your `my_type` and `L1` is the `placeholder` . So, in essence the above struct is nothing but `add_my_type` which I had shown in my initial response.

If I am correct till now, `le_result1` is the `operation` that would be performed on your `sequence`.

Comment: thank you for your help. I was under the impression that `my_type<_1>` is essentially  transformed later into a unary metafunction class via mpl::lambda. I am still not very clear why that is not the case since a single argument is passed to `my_type`. Could you explain a bit more why `my_type<_1>` is not considered as a valid unary metafunction class please?

Comment: Have updated my answer. Hopefully it should be clear now.

Comment: I am afraid I do not agree with "as required by the transform metafunction which is have a type field to indicate the transformed type". For instance if you change `my_type` to `template <class T> struct my_type{} `, the code compiles and gives the desired output, even though `my_type` still does not expose a `type` field.

Comment: Or to put it differently, even if I add a `type` field to the variadic `my_type` the code will still not compile.

Comment: @linuxfever Hmm..so you want me to do the hard work :) Challenge accepted.

Comment: @linuxfever Added the reasoning in detail.

Comment: So am I right to say that the reason why it will not work with the variadic `my_type` is because the `template< typename P1 > class F` in `le_result1` expects a template class argument accepting a single paramter (`P1`) and will not accept a variadic one? thank you for all your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130036/discussion-between-linuxfever-and-arunmu).